# Recursion and asynchronous methods with a flag variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, recursion

I have the following method:

```
function getRelevantArticles(amount, 
                             userSuggestions, 
                             suggestionPage, 
                             relevantArticles, 
                             continueFlag, 
                             success, 
                             error)
{
     if(continueFlag)
     {
         getSuggestedArticles(suggestionPage, userSuggestions, function (articles)
         {
              if(articles.length == 0)
                    getRelevantArticles(amount, userSuggestions, suggestionPage, relevantArticles, false, success, error); // continueFlag= false

              getUnvisitedArticles(articles, function (unvisited)
              {
                  for(var i = 0; i < unvisited.length; i++)
                      relevantArticles.push(unvisited[i]);

                  relevantArticles= filterRelevant(amount, userSuggestions, relevantArticles);

                  if(relevantArticles.length < amount)
                      getRelevantArticles(amount, userSuggestions, suggestionPage + 1, relevantArticles, true, success, error); // continueFlag= true
                  else
                      getRelevantArticles(amount, userSuggestions, suggestionPage, relevantArticles, false, success, error); // continueFlag= false

              }, error);
         }, error);
     } 
     else if(success)
     { 
         fillWithContent(relevantArticles, success, error); //Should be last method to execute
     }

}
```

---

### The context

I know it may be hard to understand and can be optimized a lot, I'll try my best to explain what it's doing (or trying to):

The method is first called with a flag of `continueFlag= true`, so it starts by calling `getSuggestedArticles`, which is an async method that makes an AJAX request. I pass in a callback function with the result of the request.

`getSuggestedArticles` gets me the article Ids related to the user suggestions. (The user suggestions is a list of topics that may be of interest to the user).

I pass in a `suggestionPage` because the suggestions can be a lot, and I should be able to get the relevant articles with just a few (the first page).

If no articles are retrieved, then it means we are out of suggestions (every suggestion has at least one article), i. e., we reached the last page, so we set the `continueFlag` flag to `false`, to call the finalizer method.

If there is at least one article, I call `getUnvisitedArticles`, which is another asynchronous method that makes an AJAX request. This method gives me the articles that were not visited or read by the user, which are the ones I care about.

I have a `relevantArticles` variable which keeps track of the articles that I found out to be relevant and will be presented to the user. Once I get the relevant ones from my current page of unvisited articles, and have appended them to the previous page's relevant ones, I check if I have the minimum `amount` of articles to show.

If I don't yet satisfy the minimum amount, then I go on with the next page (`suggestionPage + 1`);

If I reached the minimum threshold, then I go on with the finalizer method (`continueFlag= false`)

`fillWithContent` is the method which will be called when I finished identifying the relevant articles. It is an asynchronous method that will make an AJAX request, and will fill my article objects with additional information.

### getSuggestedArticles(Number: suggestionPage, Array: userSuggestions, Function: success, Function: error)

Receives an array of user suggestions, and takes the **nth** page of this array (page size 100).

Let's suppose we call the method like this:

```
getSuggestedArticles(0, [ 745, 4567, 1500 ], function (data) {
      var articles = data;
}, error);
```

The method makes request to Database Web API, and pass an array of suggested articles to the `success` function. In the preceding example, the `articles` variable would have an array like this (Note that all the returned suggested articles **have at least one user suggestion** among their topics):

```
[
    {
         id: 12345,
         topics: [ 998, 1500, 323 ] //has user suggestion 1500
    },
    {
         id: 45778,
         topics: [ 009, 1500, 745] //Has user suggestion 745 and 1500
    },
    ...
]
```

### getUnvisitedArticles(Array: articles, Function: success, Function: error)

Receives an array of articles and returns all the ones who weren't visited by the user.

Let's suppose we call this method like this:

```
//We are using the same "articles" variable from the previous example
getUnvisitedArticles(articles, function (data) {
     var unvisited = data;
}, error);
```

The function makes request to the Database Web Api and pass an array with the unvisited articles to the `success` function. In the preceding example, the variable `unvisited` would have an array like this:

```
[
      {
           id: 45778,
           topics: [ 009, 1500, 745]
      }
]
```

Notice that article with id **12345** is gone. This is because it has been visited by the user.

### fillWithContent(Array: relevantArticles, Function: success, Function: error)

Receives an array of articles and fill these objects with additional information.

Let's suppose we call this method like this:

```
 //We are using the same "unvisited" variable from the previous example
 fillWithContent(unvisited, function (data) {
     filledArticles = data;
 }, error);
```

The function makes request to the Database Web Api and pass an array with the filled articles to the `success` function. In the preceding example, the variable `filledArticles` would have an array like this:

```
 [
       {
           id: 45778,
           topics: [009, 1500, 745],
           title: 'Article title',
           publicationDate: 'Some date',
           author: 'Some author',
           ...
       }
 ]
```

**This is the array my caller is expeting**, by caller I mean the one calling my `getRelevantArticles` function.

---

### The problem

**The problem with this method is that `fillWithContent` is called infinitely, therefore causing a great deal of requests to be made, the browser to crash, and a recursion overflow to arise**.

I'm not calling this method from another place, so it has to be a problem with this function.

I writed a `console.log(suggestionPage)`, and it seems it keeps on incrementing the variable infinitely too. It should have stopped at page `3`, because `articles.length == 0`. But it's not stopping.

What is going on here?

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?

Comment: Your question is pretty complex. It would be a big improvement if you showed a set of example values and explained the exact Ajax requests (parameter lists) and responses (JSON) that you expect from this set of values, as well as the final result when everything is done.

Comment: (Background: Your approach is convoluted, I would rewrite it if I understood your data model better.)

Comment: @Tomalak See edited question. Please, tell me if there's something you don't understand

Comment: So, to wrap it up in one sentence: Your **input** is an array of article IDs (`userSuggestions`) and you want to map that through a number of Ajax requests (100 IDs per request) to an **output** of relevant (i.e. filtered) articles, which you then want to render on the page. Right?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, `userSuggestions` is my **input**. But `userSuggestions` is an array of **topic** ids, from which I get the **article** ids calling `getSuggestedArticles()`. You got all the rest right!

Comment: I see. Let's see what I can come up with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85224/discussion-between-tomalak-and-mati-cicero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should split your workload into independent parts that are easy reason about and easy to combine for more complex results.

As I understand it, the work consists three basic parts, all done through Ajax:

1. [topic IDs] to [article stubs for those topics] (getSuggestedArticles)
2. [article stubs] to [*relevant* (unread) article stubs] (getUnvisitedArticles)
3. [article stubs] to [full articles] (fillWithContent)

All of those Ajax requests should be made in a paged manner, e.g. 1000 items are handled by 10 requests with 100 items each.

For that we define a utility function that takes a list of items, pages them, makes an Ajax request for each page (through a worker function we pass as an argument) and returns the combined result of all requests.

```
// utility: runs an ajax request and handles errors on the low level
function ajax(options) {
    return $.ajax(options).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR);
    });
}

// utility: makes paged Ajax requests through a worker function
function pagedAjax(ajaxFunc, items, pageSize) {
    var temp = [].slice.call(items), page,
        requests = [];

    // start as many parallel Ajax requests as we have pages
    while (temp.length) {
        page = temp.splice(0, pageSize);
        requests.push( ajaxFunc(page) );
    }

    // wait until all requests have finished, return combined result
    return $.when.apply($, requests).then(function (results) {
        var combined = [];
        $.each(results, function (i, result) {
            // result is an array [data, textStatus, jqXhr]
            // push all contained items onto combined
            // (the following assumes that data is an array of objects)
            [].push.apply(combined, result[0]);
        });
        return combined;
    });
}
```

Now we can set up our three worker functions. They take arbitrary amounts of input, because all paging is done by the utility function above:

```
// worker: retrieves a list of article IDs from topic IDs
function getSuggestedArticles(topics) {
    return ajax({method: 'post', url: '/articlesByTopic', data: topics});
    // or whatever API request returns a list of articles IDs from topic IDs
}

// worker: takes a list of article IDs, returns a list of _unread_ article IDs
function getUnvisitedArticles(articles) {
    return ajax({method: 'post', url: '/unvisitedArticles', data: articles});
    // or whatever API request returns a list of unvisited articles from IDs
}

// worker: takes a list of article IDs, returns a list of articles
function fillWithContent(articles) {
    return ajax({method: 'post', url: '/articles', data: articles});
    // or whatever API request fills articles with content
}
```

After that, combining the functions is not difficult anymore:

```
// takes a list of topic IDs, requests article IDs, filters them, returns actual articles
function getUnvisitedArticlesByTopic(topicIds) {
    var pageSize = 100;

    return pagedAjax(getSuggestedArticles, topicIds, pageSize)
        .then(function (allArticles) {
            return pagedAjax(getUnvisitedArticles, allArticles, pageSize);
        })
        .then(function (unvisitedArticles) {
            return pagedAjax(fillWithContent, unvisitedArticles, pageSize);
        });
}
```

And we can use it all through a very simple call:

```
// renders unvisited articles 
function renderUnvisitedArticles() {
    var topicIds = [9, 1500, 745];

    getUnvisitedArticlesByTopic(topicIds).done(function (articles) {
        $.each(articles, function (i, article) {
            // show article on page
        });
    });
}
```

Benefits of this promise-based approach:

- No callback hell.
- Short functions that do exactly one thing.
- No self-calling functions.
- Good re-usability and testability of the individual parts.

Recommended reading is of course jQuery's documentation on [Deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Disclaimer: The code is indeed untested. If you find mistakes, tell me.

Comment: It's incredible how simple it was when using a good design. I'm new to JS programming paradigm, but I learnt a lot from this!

Comment: Wow, have you really managed get it to work so quickly and without prior knowledge of what's happening there? o_O

Comment: Honestly I did know about promises and saw them on action a lot of times. I was more comfortable with callbacks though, however your code with them looks pretty much organized. Changing my callbacks to promises wasn't that hard. You pretty much left me all served

Comment: Kudos, I'm impressed. (Also I'm astonished that my code runs against your setup without any testing from my end.)